# how to run two simulators on xcode 11?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm making a multiplayer game app using swift and I want to run the simulator in two different iPhones. I saw some other people access hardware > device and select iPhones, but in my simulator, I don't see the tab for hardware. So how can I run two phones simultaneously??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `File>Open Device` to open a new Simulator in the Xcode 11 Simulator app.

You can only run an app from Xcode on 1 simulator at a time. However, you can install the app on 2 different simulators, then you can manually launch it on one of the 2 (or both).

Comment: tahnk you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://rafellk.medium.com/deploy-to-multiple-ios-simulators-with-one-single-build-a3292d204f48) is a sort of hack you can do to run your build on multiple simulators / devices, however it is mainly for checking UI - it doesn't attach the Xcode debugger to the devices. It does build to multiple devices though.